# Blocking and async in wcf

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

This example partly is taken from stack

```
public async Task MyMethod(string s1,sring s2)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("info");
    //check input
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        Trace.TraceInformation("error");

    Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
    //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 

    //and now we call await on the task 
    int result = await longRunningTask;
    //use the result 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public async Task<int> LongRunningOperation() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); //1 seconds delay
    return 1;
}
```

I want the MyMethod to be not blocking.

1.so is it correct that until `Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();`
 the user is blocked?Should I runn the above part of code (the trace and input check) asynchronously too?if yes how? is there a way to do that without new async method implementation?

2.When we start:

```
Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
```

starts executing `LongRunningOperation` 
independent work is done on let's assume the Main Thread (Thread ID = 1) then await `longRunningOperation` is reached.

Now, if the longRunningOperation hasn't finished and is still running MyMethod() will return to its calling method, thus the main thread doesn't get blocked. When the longRunningOperation is done then a thread from the ThreadPool (can be any thread) will return to MyMethod() at its previous state and continue execution (in this case printing the result to the console).

A second case would be that the longRunningOperation has already finished its execution and the result is available. When reaching the `await longRunningOperation` the compiler knows that it has the result and will keep on executing code on the very same thread. (in this case printing result to console).

3.What happens if exception is thrown during async method?

4.If the synchronous implementation is provided can I use it?how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are incorrect about where the code retuns to the user.

Everything up to `int result = await longRunningTask;` is run on the same thread as the function that called `MyMethod(`, not the `Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();` call.

If you want the synchronous portion of the function to also run in a background thread wrap the call to `MyMethod` in a `Task.Run(`

```
var myMethodTask = Task.Run(() => MyMethod("foo", "bar"));
```

you then can `await` or whatever you need on that returned task.

2. If `longRunningTask` is  complete by the time you reach `await longRunningTask` the function will still continue to run on the same thread and never return to the caller till it reaches the end of the function. When it reaches the end of the function it returns to the caller with a `Task` already in the completed state.

If `longRunningTask` was not done it will return to the caller at the point of the `await` and return a `Task` that will change from the `Running` state to the `Completed` state when the function completes. When the `await` returns it uses the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that was active when the task started to figure out what thread it should continue it's work on. If you where on the UI thread when you hit the `await` the work will continue [on the UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by default it will use a ThreadPool thread to continue the work if there was no `SynchronizationContext` set.

3. If a exception is thrown you see the exception when `await longRunningTask` returns (or the parent thread returns if you wrapped the function in a `Task.Run(`)

4. You should use a separate method for the synchronous implementation. See the two Microsoft blog posts "[Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)" and "[Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)"